# Handle next events after seeing a specific number of them

Tags: swift, rx-swift

What I'm attempting to do is subscribe to an observable that emits a sequence of `Enums`. The goal being that every time I've seen 3 `Enums` of a specific kind that my `onNext` is called. Below is what I've attempted However, it only works once. It doesn't continue on. I'm wondering what is the best way to handle this.

```
enum Baseball {
 case strike, ball, hit
}

let bag = DisposeBag()
let subject = PublishSubject<Baseball>()

subject.filter { $0 == .strike }
  .elementAt(2)
  .subscribe(onNext: { _ in print("3 Strikes you're out") 
}).addDisposableTo(bag)

// First batter
subject.onNext(.strike)
subject.onNext(.ball)
subject.onNext(.ball)
subject.onNext(.ball)
subject.onNext(.strike)
subject.onNext(.strike) // 3 Strikes you're out is printed

// Second batter
subject.onNext(.ball)
subject.onNext(.ball)
subject.onNext(.hit)

// Third batter
subject.onNext(.strike)
subject.onNext(.strike)
subject.onNext(.strike) // Would like this to fire as well
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the buffer operator:

```
subject.filter { $0 == .strike }
    .buffer(timeSpan: 3e7, count: 3, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .subscribe(onNext: { print("3 Strikes you're out") })
    .addDisposableTo(bag)
```

This will now emit every time there are three strikes, or about once a year.

If you don't like the fact that it times out every year, you can write your own buffer operator that just takes a count:

```
extension Observable {
    func buffer(count: Int) -> Observable<[E]> {
        return Observable<[E]>.create { observer in
            var elements: [E] = []
            let lock = NSRecursiveLock()
            return self.subscribe { event in
                switch event {
                case .completed:
                    observer.onCompleted()
                case .error(let error):
                    observer.onError(error)
                case .next(let element):
                    lock.lock(); defer { lock.unlock() }
                    elements.append(element)
                    if elements.count == count {
                        observer.onNext(elements)
                        elements = []
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a fun exercise.

### Buffer

As shown by @daniel-t, this approach takes a `.buffer` of capacity 3 and when it is full, you know there were 3 strikes.

### Counter

In addition to the `buffer` approach, you can also use a counter:

```
let subject = PublishSubject<Baseball>()

let strikes = subject.asObservable()
    .filter { $0 == .strike }
let ticker = strikes.map { _ in () }
let counter = ticker.scan(0) { (memo, _) -> Int in memo + 1 }

strikes.withLatestFrom(counter) { strike, count in (strike, count) }
    .filter { _, count in count % 3 == 0 }
    .subscribe(onNext: { _ in print("3 Strikes you're out")
    }).addDisposableTo(bag)
```

With another operator or two, one could also make the increasing strike counter reset to 0 after 3.

### Index as Counter

```
let subject = PublishSubject<Baseball>()

let strikes = subject.asObservable()
    .filter { $0 == .strike }
// Unlike the counter, this starts at 0 and reports "% 3 == 0" too early.
strikes.mapWithIndex { _, index in index + 1 }
    .filter { $0 % 3 == 0 }
    .subscribe(onNext: { _ in print("3 Strikes you're out")
    }).addDisposableTo(bag)
```